# excel reference the first column of table

Tags: excel, position, formula

```
Dog     Cat     Bird    Gary  
A       0       C       100%
B       0       B       
C       ok      D       100%
D       ok              100%
E       no      A       
F       ok      F       100%
```

Is it possible to reference the 1st 2nd or 3rd column by column number/position instead of column header? So instead of

```
Table1[@Dog]
```

It would look more like this.

```
Table1[@(1st column)]
```

In VBA it is.

```
ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1)
```

But I need to know if there is a formula  way to do this?
Also Just to make clear I DO NOT want to know what column number or letter it is in the worksheet. I want to reference the 1st column by position within the table, NOT header name. TY

Comment: The `@` symbols would mean the cell in that column in  the same row as your reference formula. Is that what you want? Or do you want the entire column as in your VBA example?

Comment: I want to reference the cell with @. Like 'INDIRECT(Table1[@(The 1st table column)]' and not 'INDIRECT(Table1[@Dog])  TY

Comment: I forgot to mention I CANNOT use cell references.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to refer to cells in the same row as your formula, which is what it looks like from your question, you can use `INDEX`.

[image]

Above, the formula `=INDEX(Table2[@],2)` refers to the second column in the same row as your formula.

If you don't want to refer to the row the formula is in, just refer to the whole table and INDEX on the row and column. For example, this refers to the fourth row in the second column:

`=INDEX(Table2,4,2)`

Note that `Table2` refers to the data area of the table - not the headers - just like a database table.

Comment: not that this was asked as part of the original question, but I was wondering if you can pull a specific row from the table as well if you were referencing the table from somewhere else that was not lined up with the table?

Comment: I was just reading the [index description on the MS site](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/INDEX-function-A5DCF0DD-996D-40A4-A822-B56B061328BD), and they say index( array, row, column). but none of their examples are with table.  Looking at your formula, I would have thought Table2[@] would have been your whole table as an array, and the 2 would have referenced the second row, but instead its grabbing the second column.  left me a little confused.

Comment: @ForwardEd, the convention is that @ always means the same row. `Table2` is an actual defined name assigned to the whole data area of the table (you can see it in the Name Manager/CTRL-F3).

Comment: Dang it, now I want to upvote your edit to your answer! but I already upvoted the answer!  Thanks for the education Doug.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the good follow-up questions. Made it a better answer.

Comment: You should put that part about the header row not counting in your answer.  I would have missed that

Comment: @DougGlancy Well It was working until I tried Using it with what I already had. Is this the only way you know of. Without using the name of the table. I have this VBA that gets the name of the table, but I need to reference at least on of the cells in the table. 'Function ActiveCellTable(r As Range) As String
 ActiveCellTable = r.ListObject.Name End Function' There are several tables, they are not always in the same location on the sheet so cell references wont work and the headers might change.

Comment: @mouthpear Posting a question "How to find the right table on your excel sheet using VBA" would be a good approach.

Comment: I agree with @ForwardEd. This question was specifically non-VBA. If you have a VBA question, please post it as a new one.

Comment: @ForwardEd My question is NOT a VBA question. I asked for a formula to get the first column in a table. THAT IS THE QUESTION.  I was referring Doug's answer that although it works it HOWEVER does not work with what I have. I posted the VBA code to see If he knows any other possible formula based solution. So NO, the title is correct. Yours would be wrong since that is not what I am looking for. Since I am looking for how to "excel reference the first column of table".

Comment: @DougGlancy I was suggesting that you ask a second question on how to incorporate the information you have here into your existing VBA code.  Two separate questions 1) how to find the column of a table 2) how to Identify a specific table for use in VBA.  I was not suggesting any changes to the title of this question.

Comment: @Mouthpear, it's too bad you're shouting at somebody who is trying to help you. Perhaps the fact we both don't understand what you want is a clue that your follow-up question is unclear. Good luck.

Comment: @DougGlancy I am not "shouting" at anybody. If you are referring to the words that are in all CAPS, Those are capitalized to bring attention to them. An exclamation point would have denoted "SHOUTING".

Comment: @ForwardEd did you actually mean to direct that last comment to me? Still you have it wrong. I am not asking "how to Identify a specific table for use in VBA" NOT at all. I asked if there was any other formula that will reference the first column. I HAVE made this Abundantly clear. The only reason I provided the VBA code UDF(User Defined Function)  is because it it just that. It is not like I could of asked "How can I use your INDEX function in the INDIRECT function?" simply because he does not know MY UDF. That is why it was provided.

Comment: @Mouthpear Yes I did mean it to you, I accidently put it to Doug..sorry Doug

Comment: @mouthpear By placing your second question as a separate post and supplying a snippet of your code in doing so others may have been able to point out why what we have here is not working in your code.  They may have a work around or potentially some suggested tweaks to your code that would allow it to work. That would be a separate issue & why it should be asked as a separate question. Just like if you asked how to use INDIRECT in the INDEX function should be a separate question.  Apologies if suggestions are frustrating you, at least that is the way your responses are reading.

Answer (score 0):

Offset formula.
If Dog is in A1 and you want BIRD in C1 then you would use this formula

```
=Offset(A1,0,2,1,1)

=Offset(Refecence Cell, X, Y, B, D)
```

Offset starts a range, down X rows and over Y columns from the reference cell (first tow numbers) and returns a range the size of the second two numbers of B rows and D columns.

Here is a link to a description of the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)